# openssl error SSL_ERROR_SSL in c++ application

Tags: c++, sockets, openssl

When I use openssl to create an ssl base server-client program, the SSL_accept in the server side and the SSL_connect in the client side are both return an error named 'SSL_ERROR_SSL', how can I fix this?

Comment: You might need to add a bit more info here and some code.

Comment: I used ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr), the ssl library says 'SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher', how can I deal with this?

Comment: What cipher list did you initialize the client SSL_CTX with? What cipher list did you initialize the server SSL_CTX with?

Answer (score 2):

Check that `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()` is called after `SSL_library_init().`

Many chipher suites requires a certificate before the suite can be used.
Please check that certificates exists.